# Rails - Ajax with unobtrusive javascript Jquery UI Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to implement a progress bar I got off JQUERY UI and set the max to whatever number the user gives and have the value set to how much is needed .

I have an ajax form for volunteers on my event show page, and everything is working fine.

However, after I try to create a new volunteer every progress bar on the page updates to the one that was just created.

Heres my javascript that I just threw into my _stuff partial to be rendered out:

```
%ul.thumbnails

- @stuffs.each do |stuff|
    = javascript_tag do 
        var a = parseInt($('.quantity-have').text());
        var b = parseInt($('.quantity-needed').text());
        $(".progressbar").progressbar({value: a, max: b });
```

Here's a link to a pic of what's going on:

[image]

So I just hit the volunteer button on the first item.....
Entered the info on the volunteer form 
an ajax call is made in the create action 
and my

create.js.erb

```
$("#new_volunteer").hide();
$('.form').fadeOut();
$('.overlay').remove();
$('.item-collection').html('<%= j render("stuffs/stuff") %>');
```

just does some hiding and showing of elements.

I just want it to update the progress bar on the one that I am working on....

working with ajax is still a little new to me......

Here's the entire partial that gets rendered out after the ajax call

```
%ul.thumbnails
- @stuffs.each do |stuff|
    = javascript_tag do 
        var a = parseInt($('.quantity-have').text());
        var b = parseInt($('.quantity-needed').text());
        $(".progressbar").progressbar({value: a, max: b });
    %li.span4.items{id: stuff.id}
        .thumbnail{style: 'padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 0 !important;'}
            - if stuff.photo.file?
                = link_to(image_tag(stuff.photo.url, style: 'height: 200px; width: 300px;'), admin_event_stuff_volunteers_path(@eventable, stuff.stuffable, stuff, style: 'height: 200px; width: 300px;')) 
            - else 
                / = link_to(image_tag('placeholder.jpg'), admin_event_stuff_volunteers_path(@eventable, stuff.stuffable, stuff))
            .caption
                %h4
                    = link_to stuff.name, admin_event_stuff_volunteers_path(@eventable, stuff.stuffable, stuff), style: 'color: #555555;'
                %b
                    Item Goal:
                %span.quantity-have
                    = stuff.quantity_have.to_i
                    out of a total of 
                %b.quantity-needed
                    = stuff.quantity_needed
                %br
                    .progressbar
                        / Quantity Have:
                        / = stuff.quantity_have.to_i
                - if stuff.quantity_needed.to_i == stuff.quantity_have
                - else
                    = link_to "Volunteer", new_admin_event_stuff_volunteer_path(@admin, stuff.stuffable, stuff), class: 'btn btn-success add-volunteer', remote: true
                    - if stuff.buy_link.present?
                        = link_to "Where to buy this", stuff.buy_link, class: 'btn btn-warning volunteer'
```

It's being rendered out on my show page for EVENTS MODEL 
(don't know if that's relevant just thought I'd throw that in there)

I know why it's doing this because in my javascript I'm just telling it to find the value of just one of the posts but I need to find the value of each individual post.

Answer (score 2):

In your `$(".progressbar").progressbar({value: a, max: b });` line you're initializing the progress bar on *all* existing progress bars - you need to make sure that you're only targeting the relevant one in your loop.

To do this try setting an ID on each progress bar that is unique, eg: `.progressbar{id:"progressbar-#{stuff.id}"}` and then changing your javascript to reference that specific ID as well:  `$("#progressbar-#{stuff.id}").progressbar({value: a, max: b });`

Comment: do i have to escape it somehow in my javascript?  I see what your doing and its a good idea but its not working.....im not getting any errors its just not rendering on the page

Comment: in my js file i dont think its referencing the correct thing with stuff.id

Comment: is it not possible to use $(this) in the js.erb file?

Comment: Are you able to check the source code of the generated page and see if the ID for the progress bar gets rendered correctly, as well as the ID in the Javascript that's called in via AJAX?

Comment: I am able to check the source code....the apporpriate ID is being set....#progressbar-14.....I am unsure how to check the Javascript for the AJAX call though.....how can i use stuff.id in my JS.ERB file though?  does it know what stuff means?

Comment: @user1502223 you are passing the stuff value to the create create.js.erb with this path setting:

Comment: To pass ```stuff``` to your ```create.js.erb``` you just need to set the instance variable ```@stuff``` in your ```create``` controller function. Then, inside your ```create.js.erb``` you can refer to ```@stuff.id```.

Answer (score 0):

In the create action of your controller, make sure to return the id of the progress bar you want to update:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render "create", locals: {id: stuff.id} }
end
```

Then, using that id, you can update the correct item's progress bar. Make sure to set the id of the `.caption` element to the value of `stuff.id` (instead of setting the progress bar id) so that you can update the correct progress bar with the correct quantities in the `create.js.erb` file:

```
var a = parseInt($('#caption_#{id} .quantity-have').text());
var b = parseInt($('#caption_#{id} .quantity-needed').text());
$("#caption_#{id} .progressbar").progressbar({value: a, max: b });
```